# Apple Mach-O Link

Tags: ios, objective-c, mach-o

I got an error while compiling my code.  The issue identifier labels it as 'Apple Mach-O Link Linker command failed'.  I have no clue what this is so I have not been able to find a solution.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XYZFlipsideViewController in:
    /Users/studentuse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSC-      
aardgrngtzicssfffcbdqsezpqmv/Build/Intermediates/RSC.build/Debug-    
iphonesimulator/RSC.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZAppDelegate.o
    /Users/studentuse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RSC-  
aardgrngtzicssfffcbdqsezpqmv/Build/Intermediates/RSC.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/RSC.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZFlipsideViewController.o
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) //This    
line has the mistake
```

What is the problem with the code?

(This is only part of the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **you have defined the implementation of the class `XYZFlipsideViewController` twice**, and the linker can't figure out which definition you meant:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XYZFlipsideViewController
```

The two places it is defined in are these two object files:

```
XYZAppDelegate.o
XYZFlipsideViewController.o
```

There are two possible explanations:

- You have a `@implementation XYZFlipsideViewController ... @end` block in both of the source files `XYZAppDelegate.m` and `XYZFlipsideViewController.m`, *or*
- You have the `@implementation ... @end` block inside a header file which is `#include`/`#import`ed by both of those source files

In the first case, the solution is to remove one of the `@implementation` blocks.  In the second case, the solution is to **move the `@implementation` block from the header into the source file**, but keep the `@interface` block in the header file.

It's important to understand the distinction between `@interface` and `@implementation` -- the former says "Here is the name of a class, the names of its instance variables, and the names of its member functions", whereas the latter says "Here are all the definitions of the class's properties and member functions".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and check your actual project directory for multiple files of the file it says you have duplicates of. Sometimes I forget to click send To trash vs remove reference when deleting and re creating files.

I am not sure this is your problem, but I have had similar problems like this before.

Good Luck! ^^